# How to change css of a grid cell of a row in Extjs 4.1.3

Tags: css, extjs, extjs4.1, styling

I have an ExtJs grid, whose 1st row is used as temporary row. In the grid certain columns are non-editable. I want to show non-editable cells of first row(temporary) as non-editable. As that temporary row does not have any values so how to show those cells as non-editable (like greying out that cell only)

As selected in the image, I want to show those cells as greyed out

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Obviously this will be achieved by applying a CSS rule to those elements. To target the column we will be using the [tdCls](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-tdCls) column config.

> A CSS class names to apply to the table cells for this column.

To target the row, usually the [getRowClass](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/api/Ext.view.Table-method-getRowClass) method is used, but in this this particular case I think this will be an overkill, because it will be called on every row of the grid, we just need a class for the first row. So I think the way to go is by adding the class to the first row on view's [viewready](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/api/Ext.view.AbstractView-event-viewready) event.

That being said, here is how the solution could look. Add a `tdCls` for the needed columns:

```
{
    text: 'Serial',
    dataIndex: 'serial',
    tdCls: 'serial-column',
    width: 200
}
```

Add a class to the first row:

```
viewConfig: {
    listeners: {
        viewready: function (view) {
            Ext.get(view.getNode(0)).addCls('first-row');
        }
    }
}
```

Then just apply the needed styling via CSS:

```
.first-row .serial-column {
    background: #ccc;
}
```

Here is a working fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/26aq

**P.S.**
This is a really good tutorial about styling ExtJS grid cells: http://skirtlesden.com/articles/styling-extjs-grid-cells